# Android how check for double entry in my sqlite db?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, list

So I have a db in my app that gets build when the app is first open through an Helper class, I can add (it adds if just use dbfavoritosHelper.insert(favId, favName, favType);ourCursor.requery();Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El medio a sido a tus favorites!" inside the Agrefav button,)) and delete items from it with no problem, but what I want to accomplish is at the moment of pressing the adding button to check is an item with the same favId already exist, so if it does I don't want to add it because I don't want to create a duplicate so I want to update that item, so far the code I have is not working here it is:

in my main activity

```
//this is how I call insert
 Button Agrefav = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFav);
            Agrefav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(arrayOfWebData.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "No hay medio para agregar a favoritos!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    if(!dbfavoritosHelper.find(favId)){
                         dbfavoritosHelper.insert(favId, favName, favType);
                    ourCursor.requery();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "El medio a sido a tus favoritos!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        dbfavoritosHelper.update(favId, favId, favName, favType);
                        ourCursor.requery();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "El medio se a actualizado en tus favoritos!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }});


//this is how I call delete
dbfavoritosHelper.delete(delId);
                     delId=null;
                     ourCursor.requery();
```

in my helper:

```
 //this is how I insert items to table
 public void insert(String mId, String mName, String mType) {
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("medioId", mId);
    cv.put("medioName", mName);
    cv.put("medioType", mType);

    getWritableDatabase().insert("favorito", null, cv);

}

//this is how I'm trying to find if an item already exists in db, but not working
public boolean find(String mId){
    try {
    getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM favorito WHERE favorito.medioId='"+mId+"';", null);

    return true;        
    } catch (SQLException sqle){
    return false;   
    }
}

//this is how I update items
public void update(String id, String mId, String mName, String mType){
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    String[] args={id};
    cv.put("medioId", mId);
    cv.put("medioName", mName);
    cv.put("medioType", mType);
    getWritableDatabase().update("favorito", cv, "_id=?", args);
}

//this is how I delete them
public void delete(String id){
    getWritableDatabase().delete("favorito", "_id=?", new String[] {id});
}
```

any recommendations are welcome, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also let your table check for you.  Here's an example in SQLite:

```
create table foo (
  name text unique);

insert into foo (name) values ("Pablo");
insert into foo (name) values ("Pablo"); // Doesn't add row!
```

So if we change your insert function a little to catch the constraint exception and have it return true/false:

```
public boolean insert(String mId, String mName, String mType) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("medioId", mId);
    cv.put("medioName", mName);
    cv.put("medioType", mType);

    try {
        getWritableDatabase().insertOrThrow("favorito", null, cv);
        return true; // Won't be executed if an error is thrown
    }
    catch(SQLiteConstraintException e) {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: But this way won't send a false return or can you ?

Comment: Whoops! My example was _wrong_, I forgot to change the insert function to `insertOrThrow`. This example is correct.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to change to

```
public boolean find(String mId){    
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM favorito WHERE favorito.medioId='"+mId+"';", null);
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    { return true; }else{
    return false;}
}
```